# How do you store information on access?

Tags: ms-access

Right. So I've got a system with personal information including an address. On the paper based form there is a change of address box, so I was wanting to know if there was any way you could store the previous address somewhere after editing it so that there was a table or report somewhere where there is an employee ID along with previous addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a separate table joined to the personal information table by EmployeeID.  This table should have fields for the address and a date field (maybe even a date from and date to field) - when the address is updated a new record is created in this table with the current (doesn't have a date) address and the previous address has a date added to it.

The current address can then be pulled as the date field is Null and the previous address can be looked at as it has the maximum date for that employeeID - or you can look back at addresses prior to that based on the date field.